# Stop scale_y_discrete from rearranging factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a plot with facets where I would like to force the y-axis to include all factor levels despite missing data. However, something isn't working and the y-axis labels are getting scrambled and spread out strangely.

```
set.seed(10)
data = data.frame(
  myfacet = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
  x = sample(c(1,2,3), 9, replace  = T),
  y = c("Monday", NA, NA, "Monday", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

data$y = factor(data$y, 
         levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), ordered = TRUE)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = levels(data$y)) +
  facet_grid(myfacet ~.)
```

[image]

What is causing this behavior? How can include all levels for each facet while maintaining the correct order?

Comment: You need `drop = FALSE` instead of `limits` in `scale_y_discrete`.

Comment: Or both `drop = FALSE` and `limits` if you want the NA points omitted.

Comment: Also, btw, you don't need to make it an `ordered` factor for the levels to have a particular order - using `ordered = T` really only matters for changing the default contrasts when fitting a model.

Comment: Looks like I need both as @Gregor says. Removing ```limits``` plots the NA points as data.

Comment: @Gregor Good to know-- this is a toy version of a real problem I'm working on where I do need to impose a new order, so I included it in case the ordering itself was causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, ggplot2 always plots NA values if it can.  If you don't want to plot them, another option is to remove them from the dataset prior to plotting, e.g., `na.omit(data)`.